# How can I draw an Xbox Live avatar?

Tags: xna, c#

I want to replace the main character of my 2D game by an Xbox avatar. How can I do that?
How can I add an avatar to my project?
How can I draw an avatar?

For example, I draw my main character like that:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
  spriteBatch.Draw(Main_Character,Main_Character_Position,Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

What must be changed to draw an avatar?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940232(v=xnagamestudio.40).aspx

Comment: Avatars are 3D, so you'll have to do some other work to fit them into a 2D game.  Nothing too terrible.  http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/avatar_animation_blending http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/avatar_multiple_animations http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/custom_avatar_animation http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/inverse_kinematics

Answer (score 2):

XNA includes [APIs for performing animation and rendering of avatars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940289%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx). To get an avatar into your game, you need to initialize the gamer services component by adding a new instance of `GamerServicesComponent` to your game's component list (typically in your game's constructor):

```
Components.Add(new GamerServicesComponent(this));
```

Then you'll need to get the [`AvatarDescription`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.avatardescription%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx) for the player in question. The method provided to do this is asynchronous (since for remotely-connected gamers, it may involve a download). You'll need the [`Gamer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.gamer.aspx) object for the player you want to get the avatar of, then you can do:

```
AvatarDescription.BeginGetFromGamer(gamer, LoadAvatar, null);
```

You must write the `LoadAvatar` function yourself; it should look like this:

```
void LoadAvatar(IAsyncResult result) {
  var description = AvatarDescription.EndGetFromGamer(result);
  if (description.IsValid) {
    // Store the description in a member variable for later access if
    // the retrieval was successful.
    m_description = description;
  }
}
```

(An avatar may be invalid if the player doesn't have one. In that case you may want to fall back to using the [gamer's profile picture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.gamerprofile.getgamerpicture.aspx), which is already available in an easy-to-use format you can turn into a texture.)

Now that you have the avatar data, you can use it with the [`AvatarRenderer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.avatarrenderer.aspx) by passing the avatar to [the `Draw` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.avatarrenderer.draw.aspx) of an `AvatarRenderer`:

```
var renderer = new AvatarRenderer(m_description);
var animation = new AvatarAnimation(AvatarAnimationPreset.Stand0);
renderer.World = // ...an appropriate world matrix...
renderer.View = // ...an appropriate view matrix...
renderer.Projection = // ...an appropriate projection matrix...

renderer.Draw(animation.BoneTransforms, animation.Expression);
```

This will render the avatar into the current render target. If you want to animate the avatar, the `animation` object has an `Update` method you can pass your elapsed game time into. If you just want to capture a single frame and re-use it, you may want to look into setting up a texture render target and rendering via the above into that target once, then drawing that texture as a sprite.

Comment: Another fallback in the case of lack of an avatar, rather than profile image, would be to create a random one.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gamerservices.avatardescription.createrandom.aspx